# How can I debug PHP (PHP's mail() function) without server access?

Tags: php, web-services, email, web-hosting

I have read the highly upvoted SO answers regarding PHP's mail() function and how to debug it. However, my client currently has a shared hosting plan with DreamHost, and I don't have access to his DH account or the host server, so I can't debug (or am finding it extremely difficult to debug) my PHP's mail function.

mail() is returning true, but the mail is never sent. Having read those answers, I know that I have to either edit the php.ini, reconfigure some settings, or install/change some software. Unfortunately, I have very limited (read: no) access to the server.

How should/can I debug the php? Should I try contacting DH customer support? Am I overlooking something?
Also, I have no idea how to work the error reporting. Am I doing this right? (This is my first time with PHP; I'm a Java dev)

For reference:

PHP:

```
`$errors = '';
    $proceed = True;
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    $myemail = 'myemail@hotmail.com';//I've Tried Hotmail and Gmail
    if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||
        empty($_POST['email']) ||
        empty($_POST['message']))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
        $proceed = False;
    }
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email_address = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    if (!preg_match(
    "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
    $email_address))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
        $proceed = False;
    }`

    $mailNotFailure = False;
    if($proceed)
    {
        $to = $myemail;
        $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
        $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
            " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
            "Email: $email_address\n Message \n $message";
        $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address \n";
        $mailNotFailure = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
        phpinfo();
        //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    }

    else
    {
        //header('Location: contact.html');
    }

    if ($mailNotFailure)
    {
        //header('Location: index.html');
    }
    else 
    {
        //header('Location: contact.html');
    }`
```

And the phpinfo() can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2jGmkYrR1j7TEZxTHNxM1hvVkU/view?usp=sharing).

Also, I apologize for the PHP code formatting . This is the first time it's given me a rough time. I had to include the single script as two blocks. Please excuse that.

Comment: Without access to the server, there's indeed little for you to do apart from all the "external" stuff mentioned in the duplicate (DNS config etc.). You'll need to sort it out with someone who *does* have access to the server.

Comment: Damn. Well, I already read that one (and other answers it links to). For some reason, my client thinks a typeform would be too complicated for his audience (teens and their parents) ROFL.